# Upload an image or a txt and add it into a web page automatically

Tags: php, upload

I have an uploader that make me upload files to the server.

I would like that when I upload an image, this image is automatically visible in a page of the site. Eg, if I have a site of a music band, if I upload from an administrator password protected page the poster of the next concert, and automatically in the page "events" I can see that poster.

In the same way if I upload (from another uploader) the text for that concert, this text appears in the event page in a "description of the concert" div.

Is it possible?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do that, then using the database and store the uploaded items in its coloumn is the better way..

But to answer your question

You can do something like this.

**Step 1 :**

Read all the files in your directory

```
$dir    = 'up/';
$files = scandir($dir);
```

**Step 2 :**

Do a foreach and print it in your file (If you need to display an image it can be possible and you can have links over there )

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($files as $key) 
{
    echo $i.' - '.$key.'<hr>';
    echo "<a href='up/".$key."'><img src ='up/".$key."'>".$key."</a>";
    $i++;
}
```

So you can have something like this..

```
<?php
$dir    = 'up/';
$files = scandir($dir);
echo '<h1>List of Uploaded Files</h1> <br><hr>';
$i = 1;
foreach ($files as $key) 
{
    echo $i.' - '.$key.'<hr>';
    echo "<a href='up/".$key."'><img src ='up/".$key."'>".$key."</a>";
    $i++;
}
echo 'End of Files';

?>
```

**Note :**

I am using the directory name as `up` you can have it any name of your own.

If you have this file as list.php then it should have a sub folder named as `up` and you should have files inside it.. You can have image or text file as you need.

**Update :**

If you just want to list the files, then you just need to echo it

```
<?php
$dir    = 'up/';
$files = scandir($dir);
echo '<h1>List of Uploaded Files</h1> <br><hr>';
$i = 1;
foreach ($files as $key) 
{
    echo $i.' - '.$key.'<hr>';
    $i++;
}
echo 'End of Files';

?>
```

Here's the [eval link](https://eval.in/373309)

**Update 2 :**

As the OP needs to have an anchor tag and wants to remove the directory level Here's the updated code

```
<?php
$dir    = 'up/';
$files = scandir($dir);
echo '<h1>List of Uploaded Files</h1> <br><hr>';
$i = 1;
foreach ($files as $key) 
{
    if ($i>3) 
    {
    $j = $i-3;
    echo $j."<a href='up/".$key."'>".$key."</a><hr>";
    }
    $i++;

}
echo 'End of Files';

?>
```

Here's the [Eval](https://eval.in/373345)

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried and it works, this is not exactly what I thought but it could work! I removed <img src ='up/".$key."'> because I need only a list without the images. there is some disorder in the list because of links not ordered http://valsileprova.altervista.org/upload_list.php

Comment: Yes, I would like on the one hand  have a clickable list of the uploaded files and on the other know if I can recall the uploaded images into an existing html page

Comment: You mean in the listed flies ?

Comment: no, sorry, it's a quite difficult idea to explain and also to make, i think. The idea is to make an uploader that when I upload an image automatically there is a new image ina new div in the page "events"

Comment: That's ok .. You mean to display the image instantly after upload ?

Comment: yes! (could you please also help me fixing the problem with the code above so that I resolve that problem and I can focus on this new, bigger problem?) I'm sorry if i bother you!

Comment: Cool, you have to add only  one line to that code i given `echo "<img src =".$structure.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]).">";` Here's the eval. https://eval.in/373341

Comment: I added the code in the update, it works. but now i don't have the links in the file names and in the list the first 2 file names are respectively only one and two dots

Comment: Do you want to have links in the name ?

Comment: Those above two dots are directory structure . Do you want to remove it ?

Comment: I'm really impressed by your kind patience, thank you @Sulthan Allaudeen

Comment: You're welcome :) Here's the Eval that satisfy your two needs :) https://eval.in/373345

Comment: How can I set css for the uploaded image (like size and placement)? 
Is it possible too add a way to remove the uploaded file if the user accidentally uploads a wrong file?

Comment: In your file that you upload you can add `.css` and `.js`  manually, And to remove you can use `unlink` but i recommend to use a `database` for such things

Comment: Welcome. You should start with Creating Database, Tables with columns and once you're done, you should do connectivity so that you can do all the operations easily

Comment: ouch, it seems quite difficult.. and is with unlink easier?

Comment: Ahmm Though it seems difficult it was quite interesting :) And unlink is easier enough ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79262/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-luigi).

Comment: How can I list the files uploaded not in alphabetical order but in order of upload?

Comment: can you please help me in this issue? Find someone able to solve this problem seems really hard! http://stackoverflow.com/q/30562945/4842333