# FullPage.js: issues in div positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, fullpage.js

I'm using `FullPage.js` ( for the official documentation [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs) )
I need to have in a slide (a `#section` , as called in the `.js` )
4 boxes stacked 2 by 2 that occupy all the slide, with a little margin around the slide (like in the scheme I made). I tried a lot of ways, `display: block`, `float`, `display: flex`; but I don't completely succeeded. The best is with `flex-box`, the only problem in that case is that it doesn't work with `safari` and `android browser`. Any one can give me some help? thanks!!

[image: here the scheme I made to clarify]

**UPDATE**

actually the best results are with:

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
      <header class="header" >
          <h1>HEADER</h1>     
      </header>
  <div class="content">
            <div class="contentflex"id="up">
                <div class="flex-item" id="box1">  
                </div>                
                <div class="flex-item" id="box2">
                </div>             
            </div>

            <div class="contentflex" id="down">
                    <div class="flex-item" id="box3">
                    </div>    
                    <div class="flex-item" id="box4">
                    </div>
            </div>       
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.contentflex{
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  padding-right:1.9em;
  padding-left:2em;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-top:0;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20em
}

#up, #down{
   position:relative;
}

.flex-item{

            width: 50%;
            padding-right:10%; 
            padding-left:10%;
            padding-top:5%;
            padding-bottom:5%;
}

.content{
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` for the boxes and `relative` for the sections and slides.

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/620/)

```
.section,
.slide{
    position:relative;
}
.box{
    position: absolute;
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
}
#box1{
    background: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#box2{
    background: green;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
#box3{
    background: pink;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
#box4{
    background: orange;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

With this HTML markup:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I remove the navigation dots from the mobile view? thanks

Comment: @Luigi that's a totally different question. Create another question for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. I managed to resolve the 'navigation dots' by myself. But I had another problem related (I guess) to FullPage.js [here][1] . I would be grate if you could check if it's really a FullPage interference issue. thanks  
  
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30597359/4842333